# What Wordpress plugins are necessary for an Article Directory site?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, article

Can anyone please tell me what are necessary pluging for wordpress which needs to be used while using a Article Directory site?

For e.g: 
How to use captcha in the post section?
How to create a user verification link in the email?
How to create only 2 links allowed in the body?

These are few questions in my mind

Thanks to all who are willing to answer my questions.

Cheers
Dev

Answer (score 0):

After the user creates his account, the account will then be locked until the user clicks a verification link that he will receive in his email inbox.